# Need the result of a FoxPro RLOCK() command via OLEDbCommand

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, oledbcommand

I'm trying to execute an RLOCK() command (record lock) on a FoxPro table via OleDbCommand but I need to know if the lock succeeded.  In FoxPro, the RLOCK() returns .T. or .F. to indicate if it succeeded.

How do I get that result via OleDbCommand?

Here is my current code:

```
using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(...))  //connection string with VFPOLEDB provider
{
   conn.Open();
   using(var comm = new OleDbCommand())
   {
      string cText = @"[use table in 0] + chr(13) + "
           + @"[RLOCK(table)]";

      comm.Connection = conn;
      comm.CommandText = "Execute(" + cText + ")";
      var result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

      Consle.WriteLine(result);
      comm.Dispose();
    }

    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Right now, I'm always getting back a 1 (true) even when the Lock should not have taken place due to the fact that the record is already locked by someone else.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not returning the result of the rlock() (and that you are using ExecuteNonQuery, when you should ask a return value and use ExecuteScalar instead). You would normally get back true with that code if you properly have used ExecuteScalar. In VFP each and every procedure returns .T. if no return value is specified (or call it a function if you will - in VFP procedure and function have no difference except name).

Here is a revised version of your code:

```
string myCode =
@"use c:\temp\lockTest
locked = rlock()
return m.locked
";

string strCon = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\temp";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
{
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("ExecScript", con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", myCode);

  con.Open();
  Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
  con.Close();
}
```

While this code works perfectly well, I have no idea what you would do with a useless rlock() other than learning that you can't lock it due to some reason. In real life Execscript has little value.

Comment: Nice clarification to user of NonQuery vs executeScalar calling().

Comment: Thanks so much.  For some reason, I was under the impression that ExecuteScalar() had to be used with an actual select, update, insert or delete command.  That did exactly what I needed -- Thanks!

Comment: BTW, this script has great value in my environment.  I have two systems running automated processes that need to halt execution if the other process is running.  The easiest way to handle this was to have each system lock a control record, place a code in the record and unlock the record.  The lock keeps the systems from updating the table simultaneously.

Comment: I see. I use similar notification via messaging using an intermediate table.